# How does this condition checking works?

Tags: c, pointers

I wrote a function for string reversal via pointers, The code is running fine, without bugs, but there are some things i want to know.

Here's my code:

```
char * xstrrev(char *s1, char *s2){
 register char *p = s1;
 register char *q = s2;
 char *r  = s2;
  do{

     *(s2++) = *(p++); //first copy the string, afterwards, replace it

  }while(*p);
  p--; //to eliminate trailing '\0' while reversing.
  do {
    *(q++) = *(p--); //replace contents by reverse contents,
  }while(*q);
  return r;
}
```

Here, in  the third last line, the *q must have a value `'\0'` , because, we copied the exact string previously, So, `'\0'` must have been copied.

However, when i replace my

> *(s2++) = *(p++);

with

> p++;

i.e, i only increase `p` to the end-of string, and do not copy the string to `s2`,  the condition

> while(*q)

still works. In this condition, `*q` is not supposed to have `\0`, right? How does this condition work then?

It's same when i replace, `while(*q)` with `while(*q!='\0')`

EDIT:: It's called as:

```
char  a[110]= "hello";
char f[116];
xstrrev(a,f); //reverse a and put to f
puts(f);
```

Comment: This is so undefined behavior! Change `char f[116];` to `char f[116] = "helloworld";` to see how it breaks.

Comment: Why are you setting `a` to a palindrome? How can you tell if it was actually reversed? :)

Comment: @Barmar It's the same for any other string, wait, i'll edit that.

Comment: My comment has nothing to do with the question, it was just incidental.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's working, it's totally accidental. The string `s2` the caller supplied may have `\0` at the end of `s2`. But you can't depend on this, it depends on how the caller initialized the string it's passing.

Another possibility is that the memory right BEFORE `a` happens to contain `\0`. This can happen if you have something like:

```
char something[] = "foo";
char a[110] = "nacan";
```

The memory for `something` is right before the memory for `a`, so the `something`'s trailing null will be before the first byte of `a`.

What happens in this case is that the loop copies this `\0', but it doesn't stop immediately. It keeps on copying until it eventually runs in to a`\0`in`*q`. But when you look at`f`, you just see the reverse of`a`, because of this null byte was copied.

If you want to see this happening, single-step your function in the debugger.

None of this is guaranteed by the C language, it's just how memory layout is often done.

Comment: Nope. The caller does not  supply that. See my Edit .

Comment: What do you see when you look at `s2` in a debugger at the beginning of the function?

Comment: What's the value of `f` before you call the function?

Comment: I wrote, `puts(f)` after initializing `f`  resulted in: GMING-EH-TDM1-SJLJ-GTHR-MINGW32

Comment: I think you are fortunate that whatever is on the stack immediately before s2's address has the high byte 0.

Comment: @Fred : I think that would not be the case, on *each and every* run !!

Comment: Now why, f contains these characters, if nothing is assigned it it?

Comment: @cipher: because its in the c standard

Comment: @cipher, why? The program clearly isn't using the terminating NULL from p, and it copies bytes until it copies over a '\0'. You have an extra 110 characters before overwriting the end of f. Surely you'll find a zero byte in that range in front of p, but it is just luck, because you don't get it from p.

Comment: @Barmar . But p is decremented first p-- to remove the '\0'. And while copying the contents of p to s2,(in reverse order), when p reaches first, it's not sure that the memory before it is '\0' , so, it must have shown some random characters afterwards, isn't it so?

Comment: It's not using the terminating null from `p`, it's using the terminating null from the string BEFORE p in memory.

Comment: @Fred , but we cannot be sure that something before p, is a null character, which must have resulted in q containing some other characters before ending

Comment: @cipher: you are right..that's why you have to check or use a secure string library

Comment: @0A0D , Sorry, didn't get what you meant by `have to check` can you elaborate ?

Comment: Functions that write into user-supplied strings should be given the length of the output string, so they won't write past the end of it. That's called a "buffer overflow", and is the cause of many security exploits.

Comment: @Barmar : Thanks for the info, but how does that answer my question? :)

Comment: I think that's what he meant by "have to check". The caller tells you the length, and you make sure you don't loop any more than that.

Comment: @cipher: What @Barmar is saying is that arrays decay into pointers when passed into functions in C. You can't check the size of the array by simply doing a `sizeof` either because that will only return you the size of the pointer. So if you know the size of the array, then you should pass it in so you don't go beyond the memory allocated to the array. Otherwise, you will go out of bounds and start reading garbage (which might include a `0` or `\0`, it all depends what is on the stack at the time).

Comment: @0A0D Yeah. So i am asking why not a garbage value shown in output?
. Why it always shows the reverse of given string w/o some extra garbage?

Comment: Probably because the layout of the stack frame is similar in all the cases you tried, so there's always a zero byte just before `a`.